# Есть-ли какие-то метрики, с помощью которых можно определить какая векторизация лучше?

Tags: python, sklearn

Есть-ли какие-то метрики, с помощью которых можно определить какая векторизация лучше? Единственная метрика про которую я слышал - accurancy, есть-ли какие-то другие?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

y = df['Color'].values
X = df['Label'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)

print("Train data", X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print("Test data", X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
```

обучение тестовой выборки

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vect_bow = CountVectorizer(min_df=16)

X_train_bow = vect_bow.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_bow = vect_bow.transform(X_test)

print('X_train_bow shape:', X_train_bow.shape)
print('X_test_bow shape:', X_test_bow.shape)
```

Векторизация - BoW

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vect_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=16)

X_train_tfidf = vect_tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_tfidf = vect_tfidf.transform(X_test)

print('X_train_bow shape:', X_train_tfidf.shape)
print('X_test_bow shape:', X_test_tfidf.shape)
```

Векторизация - TF-IDF

```
y_train_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test_encoded = label_encoder.transform(y_test)
```

Приведение к числовым значениям